# Improve syntax of Kotlin extension function with only one method interface applying a lambda

Tags: function, lambda, syntax, interface, kotlin

I want to improve the syntax of this extension function but I do not know how to do it.

My idea is to make a wrap of a `TextWatcher` where I am going to use only the `onTextChanged()` method.

I would like a clean solution like 
`view.setOnClickListener{}`.

This is my current code:

```
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.EditText

interface OnTextChangedListener {
    fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int)
}

fun EditText.setOnTextChangedListener(listener: OnTextChangedListener) {
    this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            listener.onTextChanged(charSequence, start, before, count)
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
        }
    })
}
```

When I call it from another class I do something like this:

```
et.setOnTextChangedListener(object : OnTextChangedListener {
    override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        foo()
    }
})
```

It works, but I would like something cleaner... with a lambda I guess.

Any idea? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass in a lambda matching the signature of the `onTextChange` method, and forward any listener calls to it:

```
fun EditText.setOnTextChangedListener(onTextChanged: (charSequence: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) -> Unit) {
    addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            onTextChanged(s, start, before, count)
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You are the 1, @zsmb13! :-)